# Изменить значения горизонтальной шкалы диаграммы

Tags: excel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы горизонтальная шкала гистограммы начиналась с нуля, а не с единицы?

Answer (score 3):

ПКМ на гистограмме, *Выбрать данные*

Правое окно - *Подписи горизонтальной оси (категории) - Изменить*. Задать диапазон подписей (указать ссылку на диапазон)

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Comment: "Спасибо" здесь нужно выражать нажатием на галочку слева от вопроса.